# Troubleshooting reverse proxy Nginx a Flask app on Docker container, returning '503 Service Unvailable' message

Tags: nginx, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn, nginx-config

I need some help. I am trying to deploy my Flask app on a virtual machine. I use Docker, Gunicorn, and Nginx. The aim is to redirect all requests from https://myapp.virtual_machine.org to my localhost:5000

### Dockerize my Flask app

I create two containers for my Flask application on a virtual machine. It is accessible at http://127.0.0.1:5000.

Here is my app.py :

```
from app import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:12.11
    #restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_USER: usr
      POSTGRES_DB: users
    volumes:
      - users-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5433

  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    image: myapp/myapp

volumes:
  users-vol:
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Utilisez une image Python pré-configurée
FROM python:3.9


# Installez les dépendances
COPY requirements.txt /var/www/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# set env variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# update packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip  \
    && pip install gunicorn \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Copiez le code de votre application Flask dans le conteneur Docker
COPY . /var/www/app

# Définir la variable d'environnement FLASK_APP
ENV FLASK_APP = app.py
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=true
ENV FLASK_ENV=deployement

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "sleep 5 && gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 app:app"]
```

The output of `docker-compose up --build` is  :

```
pgsql_1        | 2023-05-20 09:04:21.204 UTC [26] LOG:  redo starts at 0/2B9C4F8
pgsql_1        | 2023-05-20 09:04:21.204 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/2B9C5E0: wanted 24, got 0
pgsql_1        | 2023-05-20 09:04:21.204 UTC [26] LOG:  redo done at 0/2B9C5A8
pgsql_1        | 2023-05-20 09:04:21.581 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (8)
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: sync
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
givemeasign_1  | [2023-05-20 09:04:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

## Nginx

---

My virtual machine has an IP address (xx.xx.xx.xx) and a link like myapp.virtual_machine.org. I want to access HTTP://127.0.0.1:5000 with a HTTPS protocol. I tried to create a reverse proxy with NGINX (installed on my virtual machine).

I configured nginx to have an https following this tutorial [here](https://juniarto-samsudin.medium.com/from-flask-gunicorn-nginx-to-docker-and-security-through-https-and-client-certificate-faec68a6cc63).
I have three file "ca.crt"  "nginx-selfsigned.crt"  "nginx-selfsigned.key" in the repository "/etc/nginx/nginx_cert".
I don't have any certification problems, I deduce that the problem doesn't come from there.
In the nginx configuration, I have a configuration file "myapp" in "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled" and "/etc/nginx/sites-available".

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name myapp.virtual_machine.org;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx_cert/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx_cert/nginx-selfsigned.key;
 ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx_cert/ca.crt;
 ssl_verify_client optional;
 location / {
  if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
   return 403;
  }
  root /home/student/myapp/backend;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

Thx for reading, have a good day.